# Accessing and using an extra parameter in Rails nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested

I have an Rails e-commerce app where one creates an order, then adds items to the order.

Order belongs to a User, and I have a OrderItem which is a join table for Orders and Items. Any user can create an order for other users.

routes.rb

```
  resources :items

  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    resources :orders do
      resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
    end
```

order#show renders a partial that has all Items, with a button to add an OrderItem to the Order

```
<%= render partial: 'order_items/new', locals: { user: @user, order: @order} %>
```

Here is the partial view/order_items/_new.html.erb

```
<h3>Add Items</h3>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div>
        <%= item.name %>
        <%= render 'order_items/add', locals: { user: @user, order: @order, item: @item} %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then the partial order_items/_add.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.build] do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add Item', class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

This creates the OrderItem, but item_id is nil. So I have to pass in the item_id parameter like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :item_id, :value => item.id %>
```

But the problem is that I cannot access item in the form. What's the best way to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.build(item_id: @item.id)] do |f| %>
  #....
<% end %>
```

...or if you need to see the item name (or any other attribute)

```
<%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.build(item_id: @item.id)] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label @item.name #or whatever attribute you need to see %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems that I can't access @item in the form partial.

This is the line that renders the partial, in views/order_items/_new.html.erb:

`<%= render 'order_items/add', locals: { user: @user, order: @order, item: @item} %>`

And I'm getting a NoMethodError for 'id' for nil:NilClass for @item.id

Answer (score 0):

I'm nixing the second partial, and just putting the form straight into view/order_items/_new.html.erb

```
<h3>Add Items</h3>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div>
        <%= item.name %>
        <%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.build(:item_id => item.id)] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label @item.name #or whatever attribute you need to see %>
<% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It's odd that the _form partial wasn't seeing local variable `@item`, but I now realize I don't really need to have the form in a partial.